# Building DAL. Using EDM (from database)

Tags: c#, wcf, entity-framework, visual-studio-2012

I have to develop an lob application that works in windows (wpf) but should be deployed in two flavors:

- With a local database (same computer)
- With a remote database (in the same network)

I'll use Entity Data Model generated from a database (dbcontext, EF 4.0) (VS2012, sql server express 2012)

I want to develop a unique Data Access Layer which the UI will be bound to, and it will take the data from the dbcontext directly (local database) or from a WCF Service that exposes the data from a dbcontext (remote database)

[image]

I don't know where to start, I need guidance, examples, I know that it depends on the nature of the application, but some example, article, would be of great help. I don't find an example that's similar to my needs

I guess that I better use a DI Framework, but I want to focus on the DAL first.

Comment: There is nothing WPF specific or WPF dependent in your question... removing the tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, since you want to use a DI framework (probably a good choice :)), you already know that you need to define your DAL using interfaces. Then you can have classes implementing those interfaces that act as adapters to either the WCF Service or the DB Context.

A nice aspect of your design is that you will automatically isolate yourself from possible future replacements of WCF Service & DB Context - i.e., whenever Microsoft releases yet another data access technology. :) Or more likely, whenever your team decides to adopt a different one, e.g. switching from a WCF service to a REST service.

In general the [Repository pattern](http://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html) is used to solve this. So for example you might have:

```
public interface IWidgetRepository
{
    // Query methods
    Widget GetById(string id);
    IEnumerable<Widget> GetAll();

    // Update methods
    void RenameWidget(string id, string newName);
    void UpdateWidgetPrice(string id, decimal newPrice);
}
```

If you try to make the repository interface very general, though, this becomes daunting very quickly as you start to realize that you want to have different querying capabilities, etc. (E.g., if you try to implement IQueryable in the DAL, you've got a lot of work ahead of you! I've tried, and I gave up realizing that I was just wasting effort.)

The best way around that is probably to have predefined query methods, e.g. `GetWidgetsWithOpenOrders()` and `GetWidgetsWithFooBarComponents`. Then in your adapter classes that implement `IWidgetRepository` you'll just have to implement those queries by mapping them to either the Entity Framework or WCF Service implementations.

One side effect of this is that the DAL will need its own set of data transfer objects (DTOs) - so you'll end up with a class for Widget in the DAL namespace, and potentially have other Widget classes in the DB Context and/or the WCF Service proxy. You can try to work around that by forcing the DB Context to use the same Widget class for its database mapping, but I wouldn't recommend it. The DTOs in the DB Context are there to adapt to the database, and the same goes for the DTOs in the WCF Service - they're the data contracts that the service exposes. The DTOs in the DAL are there to reflect the needs of the user interface (in MVVM terms, they're the 'Model'; in OO patterns terms they're a [Façade](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/facade) over the different data access strategies).

Another side effect is that it's very easy to create stub/mock implementations of your `IWidgetRepository` for 1) unit testing and 2) rapid prototyping of your UI without the back-end data access strategies being fully implemented.

Comment: I suppose that those methods ...GetWidgetsWithOpenOrders... will keep that data in the DAL up to date, because I want to use binding from WPF to DAL, and it is automatic, but from the DAL to the other side, how can I keep a smooth flow of data?. What do you think if I just always use the WCF Servive even when the data is local?, would it be kind of slow?. I could use IIS Express.

Comment: Sure, you can use the WCF Service as your DAL abstraction if you want to rely on that to always be there. It won't be that much slower if you code the service properly; unless you're enabling transactions, reliable messaging, security, etc. etc. on your service it'll perform very quickly. If this is an in-house application that you'll be able to maintain, that's probably the easiest to implement. But at that point you really don't need the service either; just set up your DB Context using a connection string to the remote database. Then the DB Context becomes your DAL abstraction.

Comment: But then you're giving up on the idea of flexibly swapping out your data access layer, having a separation of concerns, etc. It's a decision you have to make. I would not recommend going down that route, really. But on the other hand, "SOA" for the sake of "SOA" isn't really helpful either, it just means a lot more work for you.

Comment: I think what you missed in the repository pattern as I showed it is that the repository will also have methods for doing **updates**. I'll edit the answer to explain.

Comment: I'll appreciate your explanation... For the other side, when you say "swapping out your data access layer" you mean swapping it with Oracle, for example?

Comment: Hi, I think I didn't explain myself when I said having just the wcf service, I wouldn't bind my viewmodels directly to the service, there will be a dal, but what I meant was to having the dal always connect to the wcf service, for all cases, network and stand alone. What do you think?

Comment: Oh, okay, I understand now. Yeah, that would be fine. You still have a clean separation of concerns via the DAL, and lower implementation costs (plus a simpler solution - you can cut your testing costs down). I don't think performance will be an issue at all, though you should make your UI calls to the DAL asynchronous anyways.

Comment: Why?, I think that it generally is better, but why exactly do you think that it would improve performance?

Comment: You mean the asynchronous calls? Because in case a call to a service or database times out, the user isn't left with a hanging application. :) It's easy to do using async/await.

Comment: If you mean using a service - it won't *improve* performance; it will hurt it, but the difference should not be noticeable in many cases.

Answer (score 1):

Implement service oriented architecture where your UI will use a different service based on user or app settings and therefore instantiate different DAL objects that either access your local DB or WCF service...

-Contract

```
namespace MyUIName.Services
{
    public interface IProductServiceAgent
    {
        List<Product> GetProducts();
    }
}
```

-Agent

```
namespace MyUIName.Services
{
    public class ProductServiceAgent : BaseServiceAgent, IProductServiceAgent
    {
        //Contract implementation
        public List<Product> GetProducts()
        {
            if (Settings.Default.StoreType == "Local")
            {
                LocalStoreBIObject = new...
                LocalStoreBIObject.GetProducts();
            }
            if (Settings.Default.StoreType == "Remote")
            {
                RemoteStoreBIObject = new...
                RemoteStoreBIObject.GetProducts();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

-BI Layer

```
namespace BI
{
    public class LocalStoreBIObject
    {
        public List<Product> GetProducts()
        {
            //Do some BI stuff.
            //Instantiate appropriate DAL object
            return LocalStoreDALObjec.GetProducts(... pass in some BI params);
        }
    }
}
```

-DAL Layer

```
namespace DAL
{
    public class LocalStoreDALObject
    {
        public List<Product> GetProducts()
        {
            using (var localStoreContex = new...)
            {
                return localStoreContext.Products.Where(p => p... some logic);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This way you get a standard 3-Tier architecture with BI and DAL layers which allows you to keep your business logic in one layer and data access logic and queries in a separate layer and your service agents decide which BI layer objects to use depending on the app settings. An added benefit is that this would also allow your users to switch data stores at run-time if you need that capability...

Obviously, you wouldn't have a reference to `Product` class from your BI layer in your DAL layer so you'd have to create some intermediate objects or have a reference to your EF model in your BI or use Tuples to transport data from DAL to BI layer or find some other solution but that is just a detail you'd have to work out along the way...

Comment: what happen when two user simultaneously request the dal method.

Comment: Is it correct to give a new instance of dal to the logged in user each time it request dal.